# Can't install Twig with composer

Tags: twig, composer-php, twig-extension

I'm trying to install Twig with `composer require twig/twig` but get back:

> Could not find package twig/twig. Did you mean one of these? twig/twig

So it's suggesting to me the package I'm trying to install that it says it can't find.

Has anyone else had this before?

Answer (score -1):

Reverting to Composer 1.x could potentially cause problems down the line (in addition to being much more memory-intensive than Composer 2.x), especially if you're working on multiple projects on your machine.

What about running:

`composer require twig/twig:^1.0` (For Twig 1.x)

`composer require twig/twig:^2.0` (For Twig 2.x)

Comment: I was getting the same error with any package that I tried to install. I tried creating new projects and installing packages that I'd successfully installed just a couple of days ago before upgrading to Composer 2, and got the same error.

Comment: Did you try `composer clearcache` and  `composer why-not twig/twig:^2.0`?

Comment: Please share more details. What makes you think that providing a version requirement resolves the initial problem?

Answer (score -2):

Turns out my problem was I'd upgraded to Composer 2. When I reverted back to 1 I was able to install.

Comment: You should check whether this is a real good long-term solution, as v1 won't be supported indefinitely